# PHP & MySQL display average

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress

Ok so I have been trawling Internet for hours trying to resolve this issue but I am still at a complete lost, so would very much welcome some help or point in the right direction.

I have a MySQL query where I calculate the average of a column which is all fine.  It’s in displaying it is where I am having problems.

I've dumped the $results variable and it returns the following:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1826 (2) { ["page_id"]=> string(1) "5" ["avg(r_location)"]=> string(6) "4.0000" } }
```

The error I get also from the `echo $row...`  is:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

My code is below

```
function returnResults() {

    $postid = get_the_ID();

    global $wpdb;

    $results = $wpdb->get_results(" SELECT page_id, avg(r_location) FROM wp_ratings WHERE page_id = '$postid' ");

    var_dump($results);

    foreach ($results as $row) {
            echo $row['avg(r_location)'];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

The error message is telling you everything. You are trying to use an object as an array.

Since the result is an array of objects and not arrays you will need to add an alias to your query like this:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT page_id, avg(r_location) average 
                               FROM wp_ratings 
                               WHERE page_id = '$postid'");
```

Then you can access each value:

```
foreach($results as $row) {
  echo $row->average;
}
```

Notice that `get_results()` takes a second parameter `$output_type` which controls the return value. To get a result of associative arrays you could add `ARRAY_A` as the second parameter:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT page_id, avg(r_location) average 
                               FROM wp_ratings 
                               WHERE page_id = '$postid'", ARRAY_A);

foreach($results as $row) {
  echo $row['average'];
}
```

In this case you are not really forced to add an alias. You could access the array as you did before `echo $row['avg(r_location)'];`

Answer (score 0):

First correct your query:

```
SELECT page_id, avg(r_location) as locat FROM wp_ratings WHERE page_id = '$postid'
```

And then access it like this:

```
foreach($result as $row){
 $row->locat;
}
```